# How to divide two label value?

Tags: uilabel, nsxmlparser

I displayed  some value of web service on labels.

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

 if (

    [elementName isEqualToString:@"Unit"] ) {

    UnitLabel.text = retornoSOAP;
    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

  }


  if (

    [elementName isEqualToString:@"Total"] ) {

    TotalLabel.text = retornoSOAP;
    retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;

    }
```

I want to display Avg on other labels.Total/Unit =Average  e.g 1200.34=34=35.3041

Comment: Make that an else-if. Those `if`s can't both be true.

Comment: Sorry not clear I did not understood.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `if(...){ ... } if(...){ ... }` and `if(...){ ... } else if(...){ ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the method where you change the Unit and Total label values, check if they are both set and if they are, compute the average and set the UILabel `AverageLabel` to that float:

```
if ([UnitLabel.text floatValue] && [TotalLabel.text floatValue]) {
    AverageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", ([TotalLabel floatValue] / [UnitLabel floatValue])];
}
```

This assumes you have a `UILabel` called AverageLabel, which should display the average. I didn't test the above code.

Comment: Note I used `%.2f` as the format string for the average. If you need more than 2 decimals, you need to change that accordingly. @MehmetAkyel